# 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewitems'

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to apply below set operations on my python dictionary, in python 2.6.9

```
union = dict(set.union(*(set(service_configs[d].iteritems()) 
        for d in  service_configs if service_configs[d]))).viewitems()

intersection = dict(set.intersection(*(set(service_configs[d].iteritems()) 
               for d in  service_configs if service_configs[d]))).viewitems()
column_names = dict(union - intersection).keys()
```

above code is working in python 2.7+ however *getting 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewitems'* with prior versions, seems viewitems() is not supported.
I am Not sure how to handle this to make it python version independent.

Comment: You could just use `.items`

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am using python 2.7 for development however I would like have this code working for python version 2.5+

Comment: @PavanGupta I suggest you use Python 2.5 for development.

Comment: Nobody explains why viewitems do not exist?

Answer (score 2):

`dict.viewitems()` creates a live set-like object for all `(key, value)` pairs in the dictionary.

Since all you want to do is create an intersection here, you could just use sets from the `dict.iteritems()` sequence instead:

```
union = dict(set.union(*(set(service_configs[d].iteritems()) 
        for d in  service_configs if service_configs[d])))    
intersection = dict(set.intersection(*(set(service_configs[d].iteritems()) 
               for d in  service_configs if service_configs[d])))

column_names = dict(set(union.iteritems()) - set(intersection.iteritems())).keys()
```

As you only take the keys the above is still a very verbose way of saying:

```
union = set.union(*(d 
        for d in service_configs.itervalues() if d))    
intersection = set.intersection(*(d 
        for d in service_configs.itervalues() if d))

column_names = list(union - intersection)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `union = dict(set.union(*(set(d.iteritems()) for d in  service_configs.itervalues())))` be the same?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: only if there are no `None` or other false-y objects in `service_configs`.